# nginx configuration location regular expression

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-config

I'm using an nginx server to proxy a request to another location, but I'm having trouble getting the regex to work. I think part of my issue is that I don't completely understand how the proxy works as I copy/pasted it from somewhere else I saw online.

Here is my nginx-config file:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  location /api/data {
        proxy_pass http://jsonserverlocation:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host mywebsitewithjson.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

When I make requests like `.../api/data/types` the server redirects to the resource as expected. However, when I make requests like `.../api/data/types/C` I get a 404. How do I get the nginx to pass any request that begins with `/api/data/` to redirect with my proxy, regardless of how many slashes there are after data?

Comment: `^\/api\/data\/`

Comment: @emsimpson92 wouldn't take. In fact, I got an error saying "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0", it looks like this caused an HTML response.

Comment: sounds like it has something to do with the nginx side of things. My response was just a generic regex pattern, I'm not sure how patterns vary for nginx

Comment: Your configuration already passes any URI that begins with `/api/data` to the `jsonserverlocation:3000` service. Any 404 response is likely to be originating from there. Does the `jsonserverlocation:3000` service expect the URI to begin with `/api/data` too?

Comment: @RichardSmith I had a workaround for this that involved changing the query from api/data, so it didn't answer this question. `jsonserverlocation:3000` isn't expecting `/api/data` . When I pass the same exact argument to a localhost jsonserver with the same data it returns a result, so I don't believe it's coming from jsonserver.